# Is there a way to better configure JWPlayer's sharing functionality?

Tags: facebook, video, jwplayer

Sharing videos is critical, and it is great that JWPlayer comes with sharing functionality, but so far, I don't believe is usable for the following reasons:

- The select button does not seem to work on iOS
- The email button does not seem to work on iOS
- The facebook does not add a thumbnail/poster of the video, which IMO, means it is too basic to expose to users on a real site.

I can accept (even if I am disappointed) that the facebook interface is not too fancy but the iOS issues are a killer, preventing me to using this feature at all. I don't know if they work on Android.

Is anybody using this feature successfully? Or is this just a marketing bullet but everybody just writes their own real implementation?

Here is one link that shows how I was trying to use:

https://ampervue.com/share/video/ba834264-382c-4fae-9017-6ce134840c94/

Thanks,

Comment: All that is shared on Facebook is your article URL – so any additional information such as the thumbnail should be specified using proper Open Graph meta tags under that URL. And that is rather not the responsibility of any client-side player, but yours.

Comment: We are planning on doing a major sharing overhaul which addresses sme of the issues you mention. The FB issues have to do with adding OpenGraph tags on your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question on at least the facebook issue, the solution is to add the proper facebook tags to the page being shared. To display an image, the following tag needs to be added:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://graphics.myfavnews.com/images/logo-100x100.jpg" />
```

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1826071-embedding-jw-player-onto-facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup

But I still don't know if there are solutions/workarounds for the iOS issues